# WiKi for an organization in GitHub -- possible?

Tags: github, github-wiki

Is it possible to create a WiKi on an organization level in GitHub? That is, I don't want a wiki in a single repository and I want to avoid creating a new empty repository only Wiki. Instead I want to create a Wiki for a whole organization. Possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 4):

One option could be to create a [GitHub pages](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/publishing-an-organization-homepage-on-github-pages-347dbd700f4e) repository and then create the Wiki there.

This article suggests to create a dedicated repository for the Wiki:
https://labs.inn.org/2014/05/19/applying-git-to-github-wikis/

Answer (score 3):

Github is a repository management system, not an all purpose hoster.  You'll have to host your Wiki either on your own servers or on a hosting account you purchase.

Comment: > Every GitHub repository comes equipped with a section for hosting documentation, called a wiki.

https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/

Comment: This is misleading. If you're looking at repo/version control management, just use Git. GitHub HOSTS these repositories, but the main feature is the _collaboration_ on top of it all.

Answer (score 2):

another option is to create a public `.github` repo with a `/profile/README.md` file.
this `README.md` will be visible on the organization home page.

in that `README.md` you can refer to repo wikis.

[read all about it here](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/customizing-your-organizations-profile#adding-a-public-organization-profile-readme)